# remembering state of activity indicator ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm showing a `UIActivityIndicator` while saving a `PFObject` (using Parse.com)

```
- (void) saveNewMessage {
    // Show Activity Indicator
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]     initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    activityView.center=self.view.center;
    [activityView startAnimating];

    // Create Message
    ...

    // Save Message
    [message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            // complete activity indicator 
            [activityView stop];
        }
    }];
}
```

**My Problem:** What if the user leaves the view while we're still saving, and then comes back to the view and the save hasn't completed yet. The `UIActivityIndicatorView` will be gone. How do I determine whether the parse operation has completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you implemented "leaving the view" and "coming back to the view"

If you use the same viewcontroller (for example pushing popping the vc with navigation viewcontroller), UIActivityIndicatorView has a method named

```
- (BOOL)isAnimating
```

You can check UIActivityIndicatorView's status

Otherwise (ie you allocate and present a new viewcontroller) you need to use a global mechanism, nsnotificationcenter might suit your needs or you may set a variable in AppDelegate or you can read/write to a local file.

Comment: Instead of a "global", the _parent_ view controller may save the state.

Answer (score 0):

You could store a `BOOL` in your view controller telling that the save operation has finished, then update it in your completion block along with the `[activityView stop];`.

Then, to handle the case where the user leaves the screen and comes back later, add a check in `- (void)viewWillAppear` to also hide the `UIActivityIndicatorView` if the save operation has completed (e.g. if your `BOOL` is set to `YES`).

Comment: This will not work when the view controller is deallocated as an effect when the user "leaves the view", and re-created when the user displays the view again.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: Since the completion block will be called anyway, a preference variable (in `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`) could be used instead of a view controller instance variable as my first answer suggested?

Answer (score 0):

PFObject actually has a built in boolean to tell us when its done saving. You may also make your save button disabled at the same time just to keep from getting multiple save requests.

```
[activityView startAnimating]

    [yourobject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
            if (succeeded) {


     [activityView stopAnimating];  
    }else{


     [activityView stopAnimating];

    }
```